# Node's coexistance with Boost.Asio

Tags: node.js, boost

There's a node already doing some repetitive works(like setInterval) and network event handling.

I've built another network library in C++ using Boost.Asio and want to use it from node I explained above(with node-ffi and it works well).

Here's the problem. Node has its own event dispatcher and Boost.Asio too. So, after I've invoked the above C++ library from node, because it blocked, no other node code could not be reached and didn't work anymore.

Can I make them to coexist peacefully...?

Comment: With nodejs owning the primary event loop, one can use an asynchronous call chain in nodejs that invokes periodically invokes [`io_service::poll_one()`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_58_0/doc/html/boost_asio/reference/io_service/poll_one/overload1.html) to process Boost.Asio's event loop without blocking waiting for operations to complete.  Consider posting a [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), as it may expose details needed to provide a thorough answer.

Answer (score 0):

Asio's io_service::poll_one() works find in some way but there's a better solution.

node-ffi's [Async Library Call](https://github.com/node-ffi/node-ffi/wiki/Node-FFI-Tutorial) is perfect for this situation. It says...

> node-ffi supports the ability to execute library calls in a different
>   thread using the libuv library. To use the async support, you invoke
>   the .async() function on any returned FFI'd function.

Comment: This may not be the _perfect_ solution for _all_ situations.  The libuv documentation notes that their thread pool size is quite limited.  Without configuration changes, applications making heavy use of the pool (filesystem operations, DNS operations, user code specified by `uv_queue_work()`) may run into starvation if one of the threads in the pool is blocking on the `io_service`.